# How to create persistent Cookie in servlet (Java) difference between the non-persistent cookie and HttpSession

Tags: cookies, servlets, httpsession

How to create persistent Cookie in servlet (Java) or both have the same Syntax only
And Difference between the non-persistent cookie and HttpSession.

```
Cookie c = new Cookie("c1",login);//create cookie
response.addCookie(c);//adds cookie with response
```

is this the way to create persistent cookie or persistent and non-persistent have the same syntax

Comment: Response is not persistent object, so you can't persist a cookie by adding it to the response.